# Speed up loop in R - using multiple cores?

Tags: r, performance, loops

I'm running quite a long loop with > 100,000 rows of data in R and it takes ~ 20 days to run. It's the Viterbi algorithm to decode the most likely state sequence for post-processing the output of a hidden Markov model.

I was wondering if there is any chance to speed up this loop? Would using more cores help, or, due to the recursive structure, can other tricks do it?

```
N_draws = 2000
N = 100000
z_star = matrix(nrow = N_draws, ncol = N)
best_logp = data.frame(matrix(nrow = N, ncol = S))
back_ptr = best_logp


for(d in 1:N_draws){
  for (k in 1:K)
    best_logp[1, k] = dnorm(y[1],
                            mean = mu[k] + X[1, ]%*%delta[d, ],
                            sd = sigma_q[d],
                            log = TRUE)
  for (t in 2:N) {
    for (k in 1:K) {
      best_logp[t, k] = -Inf
      for (j in 1:K) {
        real logp;
        logp = best_logp[t-1, j] + log(theta[j, k]) + dnorm(y[t],
                            mean = mu[k] + X[t, ]%*%delta[d, ],
                                                            sd = sigma_q[d],
                                                            log = TRUE)
        if (logp > best_logp[t, k]) {
          back_ptr[t, k] = j;
          best_logp[t, k] = logp;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  log_p_z_star = max(best_logp[N]);
  for (k in 1:K)
    if (best_logp[N, k] == log_p_z_star)
      z_star[N] = k;
  for (t in 1:(N - 1))
    z_star[d, N - t] = back_ptr[N - t + 1, z_star[d, N - t + 1]];
}
```

Comment: Try function `viterbi` in [package HMM](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=HMM). It's probably much faster than an implementation with 4 nested `for` loops.

Comment: whats `y`, `mu`, `delta`.... etc.?

Comment: y is a vector of 100,000 numeric values from the data I used to estimate the model. Mu and delta are estimated parameters, so I insert the estimated parameter for each draw.

Comment: @Scijens it would be beneficial if you could add that to code in you question. some generation of those vectors, so we can take the code and run it....

Comment: @Scijens `K`, `S`.. etc isnt defined also